# How to test testDelete() in J-Unit, how to actually test J-Unit

Tags: java, testing

Alright, so I'm working with JUnit for the first time. I have two public functions in my ListOfFraction class: add and delete. They are listed in the ListOfFractionTest class here and I was to make tests for this list(it is a growable list of size 2) That's why I tested with three fractions. The test for add I'm highly positive with. But is my delete method actually even testing anything? I guess some questions are what exactly will JUnit do in my scenario to help me and did I set up reasonable tests? Please and thanks for all and any Advice. Note::: I only have about 2 months worth of Java knowledge.

```
/**
    * Test of add method, of class ListOfFraction.
    */
   @Test
   public void testAdd()
   {
      System.out.println("add");
      Fraction z = new Fraction(1, 2);
      Fraction x = new Fraction(2, 3);
      Fraction y = new Fraction("4/3");
      ListOfFraction instance = new ListOfFraction();
      instance.add(z);
      instance.add(x);
      instance.add(y);
      // review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
      boolean expResult = true;           // we expect the result of delete to
                                          // be true since we just added it.
      boolean result = instance.delete(z);// Call actual delete
      boolean result2 = instance.delete(x);
      boolean result3 = instance.delete(y);
      assertEquals(expResult, result);    // Test the results.
      assertEquals(expResult, result2);
      assertEquals(expResult, result3);
   }

   /**
    * Test of delete method, of class ListOfFraction.
    */
   @Test
   public void testDelete()
   {
      System.out.println("delete");
      Fraction z = new Fraction(3, 2);
      Fraction x = new Fraction(3, 3);
      Fraction y = new Fraction("7/3");
      ListOfFraction instance = new ListOfFraction();
      boolean expResult = false;
      boolean result = instance.delete(z);
      boolean result2 = instance.delete(x);
      boolean result3 = instance.delete(y);
      assertEquals(expResult, result);
      assertEquals(expResult, result2);
      assertEquals(expResult, result3);
      // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default 
      // call to fail.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is muddled: Your add text is also deleting, then testing that it's not there, but if both add and delete are broken (ie do nothing), your test would still pass!

Better to add, then confirm it's been added. In your delete, it's OK to do both, because you're testing the add part separately.

Also, don't use variables like that. Change:

```
boolean expResult = true;
boolean result = instance.delete(z);
assertEquals(expResult, result);
```

To simply:

```
assertTrue(instance.delete(z));
```

Less code, easier to read, easier to debug.

Comment: This is for the add method or the delete method?

Comment: @That_Programmguy what do you mean by "this"? There are several points here. Which one?

Comment: Like any case that you find the boolean, boolean, assertEquals....should be changed to simply assertTrue(instance....)? Also I have a testProduct one that I'd like to post, would you mind taking a look at it? I'm really new to this JUnit and it seems like something I want to get a handle on.

Comment: @That_Programmguy I'll look at it no worries. Better to post it as another question. If you like, post the link to the question as a comment posted here addressed to me (start it with `@Bohemian`).

Answer (score 1):

Your delete test is trying to delete entries that you never added to the ListOfFractions.  See your add test, which appears to correct add the items and then delete them.  This isn't bad, it could be considered one test - delete items that are there.  But you probably also need to test the case where you added the 3 entries and then deleted them.

With JUnit4, it is a lot easier to create a base class that has some common code that your test class can extend from.  Or, you could create some 'helper' methods in this test class, methods like, createBaseListOfFractions() - which could build the list of 3 fractions used in both the add and delete method.  This way you get reuse of the code and the actual test methods become much smaller, calling the helper methods, then exercising the specific method and then finally asserting your conditions.